# Magento Export Search Terms and Synonyms

Tags: magento, search

Is there a way to export to csv Search Terms and Synonyms from a current Magento site?  I need to then be able to upload to a new Magento site.  I am very new to Magento and at this point I have not been able to find anything in the Admin.  Other than I was able to export the Search Terms from the reports section of the Admin.

We are using Magento Connect

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at magento commerce guideline for this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/popular-search-terms

then to disaply you can use following code as a start point

```
<h3><?php echo $this->__('Popular Search Terms') ?></h3>
<?php if( sizeof($this->getTerms()) > 0 ): ?>
<div class="box base-mini mini-product-tags">
    <div class="content">
    <ul class="bare-list">
        <?php foreach ($this->getTerms() as $_term): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getSearchUrl($_term) ?>" style="font-size:<?php echo $_term->getRatio()*70+75 ?>%;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_term->getName()) ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="note-msg">
        <?php echo $this->__('There are no search terms available.'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Hope this helps

Also you might need to use following

```
$searchCollectino=Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->getCollection()
 ->setPopularQueryFilter()
 ->setPageSize($limit);
```